# Why am I getting incorrect result from EntityClass?

Tags: curated-data, finance, entity

Suppose I want get 6 largest companies by market capitalization. I try the class using the old syntax:

```
class = EntityClass["Financial",{EntityProperty["Financial","MarketCap"]->TakeLargest[6]}]
```

Next, I try to get the list of companies along with some properties as follows:

```
EntityValue[
    class,
    {EntityProperty["Financial","MarketCap"],EntityProperty["Financial","FloatShares"],EntityProperty["Financial","Price"]},
    "Association"
]
```

I get the following output

```
<|Entity["Financial", 
   "NASDAQ:MSFT"] -> <|EntityProperty["Financial", "MarketCap"] -> 
    Quantity[1.3327607340714204`*^12, "USDollars"], 
   EntityProperty["Financial", "FloatShares"] -> 7635409400, 
   EntityProperty["Financial", 
     "Price"] -> {DateObject[{2020, 4, 24}, "Day", "Gregorian", 5.], 
     Quantity[174.5500030517578, "USDollars"]}|>, 
 Entity["Financial", 
   "NASDAQ:AAPL"] -> <|EntityProperty["Financial", "MarketCap"] -> 
    Quantity[1.2787923701165771`*^12, "USDollars"], 
   EntityProperty["Financial", "FloatShares"] -> 4519180000, 
   EntityProperty["Financial", 
     "Price"] -> {DateObject[{2020, 4, 24}, "Day", "Gregorian", 5.], 
     Quantity[282.9700012207031, "USDollars"]}|>, 
 Entity["Financial", 
   "NASDAQ:AMZN"] -> <|EntityProperty["Financial", "MarketCap"] -> 
    Quantity[1.1922298059814246`*^12, "USDollars"], 
   EntityProperty["Financial", "FloatShares"] -> 494656015, 
   EntityProperty["Financial", 
     "Price"] -> {DateObject[{2020, 4, 24}, "Day", "Gregorian", 5.], 
     Quantity[2410.219970703125, "USDollars"]}|>, 
 Entity["Financial", 
   "NASDAQ:GOOG"] -> <|EntityProperty["Financial", "MarketCap"] -> 
    Quantity[8.870714837673096*^11, "USDollars"], 
   EntityProperty["Financial", "FloatShares"] -> 693398350, 
   EntityProperty["Financial", 
     "Price"] -> {DateObject[{2020, 4, 24}, "Day", "Gregorian", 5.], 
     Quantity[1279.31005859375, "USDollars"]}|>, 
 Entity["Financial", 
   "NYSE:BRK-B"] -> <|EntityProperty["Financial", "MarketCap"] -> 
    Quantity[4.571726430808792*^11, "USDollars"], 
   EntityProperty["Financial", "FloatShares"] -> 2451064940, 
   EntityProperty["Financial", 
     "Price"] -> {DateObject[{2020, 4, 24}, "Day", "Gregorian", 5.], 
     Quantity[186.52000427246094`, "USDollars"]}|>, 
 Entity["Financial", 
   "NYSE:JNJ"] -> <|EntityProperty["Financial", "MarketCap"] -> 
    Quantity[4.087011751220388*^11, "USDollars"], 
   EntityProperty["Financial", "FloatShares"] -> 2639165527, 
   EntityProperty["Financial", 
     "Price"] -> {DateObject[{2020, 4, 24}, "Day", "Gregorian", 5.], 
     Quantity[154.86000061035156`, "USDollars"]}|>|>
```

But then I look at the market capitalization of Facebook:

```
Entity["Financial","NASDAQ:FB"]["MarketCap"]
```

I get

```
Quantity[5.422603220504935*^11, "USDollars"]
```

Note that market capitalization of Facebook is more than `Entity["Financial","NYSE:BRK-B"]` and thus it should have appeared in the list above that. So why am I getting this incorrect output.

Also how to define this `class` using the new more refined `EntityClass` functions like `FilteredEntityClass`, `SortedEntityClass` and `SampledEntityClass` etc?

Comment: You can use something like `SortedEntityClass["Financial", EntityProperty["Financial", "MarketCap"], -6]`, but it will take forever to execute because these new heads have not been optimized in alpha yet and the sorting is going to happen client-side once all the data is downloaded.

Comment: @Carlo thank you for your comment! Yes, I am facing this issue with new `EntityClass` functions since they don't seem to be doing computation on `WolframAlpha` servers and forcing users to download the entire databases. Any idea why the answer might be coming out wrong using the older `EntityClass` function?

Comment: No, but I've forwarded the question to the relevant people. I think last time we saw a bug like this it was due to a lack normalization of units before comparing

Comment: @Carlo Are you a Wolfram employee? Btw since you are checking this, `Entity["Financial","NYSE:BABA"]` also should have appeared in the list. Since you guys don't support the exchange `Saudi Aramco` is trading on, its absence can be justified. But please start supporting all the exhanges in the world like you were doing in the older versions.

Comment: One more request when `Keys` of the dataset are `EntityProperty` or `Entities` they don't typeset in the rectangular format. So for example in the association in this question if I apply `Dataset` on it, it won't typeset property. I have to use `CanonicalName` or `CommonName` on the `Keys` so I get a nicely typeset dataset. Please make dataset support the `Entity` and `EntityProperty` wrapper natively in the `Keys` and maybe add an `Option` to `Dataset` like `EntityKeys->CanonicalName  or EntityKeys->CommonName` so it doesn't become a chore to display associations with `Entities` as `Keys`.

Comment: I am a developer, but there is only so much I have worked on. You should contact tech support with these issues, they'll open a proper bug with the relevant people on it.